# WPF Select multiple items in DataGrid from ViewModel with twoway binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm trying to create a twoway binding to the selected items in a WPF `DataGrid`. I want to be able to select multiple items from the `ViewModel` and also from the actual `UserControl`. I know I cannot directly set the selected items since this property is readonly.

I'm thinking of binding to a `DependencyProperty` and subscribing to the `SelectionChanged` event of the `DataGrid` in the code behind.

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:ListView">
        <Setter Property="SelectedItems" Value="{Binding SelectedItemsVM, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid Name="ObjectListDataGrid" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
```

In the code behind I create the `DependencyProperty`. When this is set, I subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedItems
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(ListView), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<object>), OnSelectedItemsChanged));

private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var collection = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<object>;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        collection.CollectionChanged -= OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged;
        collection.CollectionChanged += OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

I use the `EventHandler` to the `SelectionChanged` event of the `DataGrid` to add/remove the items in the collection.

```cs
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    SelectedItems.Remove(args.RemovedItems);
    SelectedItems.Add(args.AddedItems);
}
```

Now I want to select the rows needed in the `OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged` method when the collection changes.

```cs
private static void OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    foreach (DataGridRow row in ObjectListDataGrid.Rows())
    {
        if(ObjectListDataGrid.SelectedItems.Contains(row.Item))
            row.IsSelected = true;
        else
            row.IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

**The problem:**
Since the `OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged` method is static, I do not have access to the `ObjectListDataGrid`. Is there any way to overcome this, or do it in a different way?

For completeness, the `DataGrid.Rows()` method is an extension method to get a list of the rows:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<DataGridRow> Rows(this DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
        if (null != row) yield return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that using the `as` operator (like `e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<object>`) only makes sense when the source object can legitimately be of any other (non-derived) type than the target type of the expression.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the comment :)

Comment: How do you mean? They are the actual items now in the code (not the item containers) and they are supposed to be that way. I'm using the actual select items in my viewmodel.

Comment: Sorry, that was nonsense. I overlooked `Contains(row.Item)`.

Comment: No problem, thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged` method must not be static.

Cast the `DependencyObject` argument of the `OnSelectedItemsChanged` method to your ListView class. Also make sure to detach the handler from the old value of the `SelectedItems` property.

```
private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(
    DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = (ListView)d;
    var oldCollection = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue;
    var newCollection = (INotifyCollectionChanged)e.NewValue;

    if (oldCollection != null)
    {
        oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= listView.OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged;
    }

    if (newCollection != null)
    {
        newCollection.CollectionChanged += listView.OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged;
    }
}

private void OnSelectedItemsCollectionChanged(
    object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var row in ObjectListDataGrid.Rows())
    {
        row.IsSelected = ObjectListDataGrid.SelectedItems.Contains(row.Item);
    }
}
```